# Create a like button for blog posts in my Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I've been trying to create a like button for my blog posts in my Django blog
but I can't figure out how to create one because it contain Integer .

When the user clicks on the like button . The like button will increase  and it will display near the post.

This is my like module:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    post_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,  upload_to="images/")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | '  + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', args=(str(self.id)),)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put two variables named `likes` and `dislikes`, Both with `ManyToManyField`.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    post_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,  upload_to="images/")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='post_like', blank=True)
    dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='post_dislike', blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | '  + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', args=(str(self.id)),)
```

Now you can make two views. One for `Like` and the other for `Dislike`